# Python Unbound Local variabel

Tags: python

Why my check_email error, i dont know how to fix it

```
def getLoginDetails():
    with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        if 'email' not in session:
            loggedIn = False
            firstName = ''
            noOfItems = 0
        else:
            loggedIn = True
            cur.execute("SELECT userId, firstName FROM users WHERE email = '" + session['email'] + "'")
            userId, firstName = cur.fetchone()
            if 'email' == "admin@shop.com":
                check_email = True
            else:
                check_email = False
            cur.execute("SELECT count(productId) FROM kart WHERE userId = " + str(userId))
            noOfItems = cur.fetchone()[0]
    conn.close()
    return (loggedIn, firstName, noOfItems, check_email)

@app.route("/")
def root():
    loggedIn, firstName, noOfItems, check_email = getLoginDetails()
    with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT productId, name, price, description, image, stock FROM products')
        itemData = cur.fetchall()
        cur.execute('SELECT categoryId, name FROM categories')
        categoryData = cur.fetchall()
    itemData = parse(itemData)
    return render_template('home.html', itemData=itemData, loggedIn=loggedIn, firstName=firstName, noOfItems=noOfItems, categoryData=categoryData, check_email=check_email)
```

This makes no sense to me as I clearly initialize check_email as one of the first lines of my code, and I even labeled it as global just to be safe and make sure it was within the scope of all my methods.

Error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'check_email' referenced before assignment

Comment: I don't know either until I see the actual error...

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'check_email' referenced before assignment

Comment: Identifying *where* the error occurs is usually pretty helpful, too.

Comment: Be afraid of Little Bobby Tables: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign to `check_email` if `'email' not in session`.